# Emulating fixed point numbers in postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, fixed-point

I want to use fixed point numbers for a table, always with 3 decimal places. I have an example table like so:

```
create table coordinates (id serial, x integer, y integer, z integer);
```

This will have hundreds of thousands of rows, but probably won't be inserted/updated very often once the initial data set is loaded. But it's going to be a pain to have to do the math to divide each of those by a thousand in every place that makes use of it. It occurred to me that a view might be appropriate:

```
create view coordinates_adjusted as 
 select id, x/1000::real as x, y/1000::real as y, z/1000::real as z 
   from coordinates;
```

This of course works as expected and I don't really anticipate any performance concerns either.

Is there a way to insert/update to this view with the fixed point numbers, such that they are then multiplied by 1000 before being inserted/updated into the underlying table? Postgres seems to support inserts on view, but not for circumstances where the view is complicated. While I won't be updating often, it will still occur and so I'd like to be consistent throughout this project.

Am I better off using a numeric/decimal for these columns? What sort of performance issues could I expect if I were to do that? I don't need anywhere near that level of precision, and I expect my data to all fit well within the extent of signed 4 byte values. I don't need a scale beyond 3, or precision beyond 13 or so. But with the values being coordinates I will be using these heavily with math.

Comment: "*but not for circumstances where the view is complicated*" - you will need to write an `INSTEAD OF` for that.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thank you, I'll do some googling.

Answer (score 2):

If you want fixed point values with three decimal points, then define the columns as [`numeric(4, 3)`/`decimal(4, 3)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC-DECIMAL).

This is what `numeric` is for.  Don't start fiddling with trying to use other types, when a built-in mechanism exists for exactly your data.

Comment: Numeric is for arbitrary precision. When you have to be absolutely certain you're not getting rounding errors. I don't believe that this is the use case they were intended for. Perhaps I'm wrong.

Comment: @JohnO . . . `numeric` with no precision or scale is a special case.  `numeric()`/`decimal()` was designed to hold fixed precision numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Use `numeric(10,3)` throughout for ease of coding and to avoid rounding errors.
2. Use `integer` or `bigint` as you do now for speed of processing, at the price of convenience and readability.

In the second case, using views with `INSTEAD OF` triggers for data modification is a way to improve convenience (but use `double precision`, not `real`), but be aware of potential rounding problems during the conversion between integers and floating point numbers.